# How To Force Redirect To Https + Non-WWW + Trailing Slash With A Single 301 Redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, no-www, trailing-slash

I want all my users to be redirected to https://example.com/subfolder/

A single 301 redirect that redirects to https + non-www + trailing slash.

How do I do this in htaccess?